# How to get video frame from AVCaptureOutput face detect metadata objects

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, avfoundation

I am able to get face detection from a video stream working following the StacheCam example from [WWDC 2012](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_sample_code/wwdc_2012_session_code.dmg).

However, I cannot get the corresponding image frame.  I have both

```
captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:
```

and

```
captureOutput:didOutputMetadataObjects:fromConnection:
```

firing and giving me data but both are asynchronous calls and I don't see a way to accurately sync a facebox with a frame.

Comment: I'm trying to do this also, I have the normalised location of the face in captureOutput receiving the metadata but can't see a way to get the actual pixel data from the frame. 
Does anyone have any experience with this?